# How can I get Intellisense to work for C# in VSCode on WSL2?

Tags: c#, intellisense, vscode-remote

I've tried several things and cannot seem to get intellisense to work for C#. I've tried:

- installing / reinstalling the C# Dev Kit
- checked the omnisharp settings (I don't have an extra extension installed)
- restarting WSL
- verifying that the SDKs are installed
- ran `dotnet` restore
- verified that the extensions are installed in WSL ubuntu
- verified that the workspace / directory is trusted in vscode
- tried switching to the pre-release version of C# dev kit
- various google searches

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There are two things required.

1. You have to be signed in to the C# Dev Kit. You can do this by running the `Welcome: Open Walkthrough` command.
2. You have to have a solution, have the project(s) added to it, and have the solution open in Solution Explorer.

Hope that helps anyone that might have the same issue.